# Abbreviation for "Dimension" and "Measure"

Tags: abbreviations

I have two terms that need abbreviation (to 3 or 4 letters).  They are from the field of Data Warehouse (Information technologies)

```
Dimension
Measure
```

One can abbreviate the first one as "dim".  Some suggested the second one be abbreviated as "mea", but somehow I find this abbreviation ugly.  Is there a better alternative?

Would "meas" be better?  Or is it even worse?

Or "msr"? (dropping the vowels)

Comment: Some context would help. Can you provide and example of how these terms are to be used?

Comment: I want to use the abbreviations as prefixes for concepts built on top of them.  E.g. I may have "dimColumn", "meaColumn", "meaFormula", "meaAdditionalAggFromFormula", "meaAdditionalAggFromColumn".  Would "msrColumn" be better than "meaColumn"?

Comment: According to AcronymFinder, mea and meas are both commonly used. 'meaAdditionalAggFromFormula' etc are hardly standard English usages and should be discussed on an appropriate computing site.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess the question in my mind really is this.  Would "msr" (i.e. by dropping the vowels) a better way to abbreviate the word "measure" than "mea"? (The latter is done by truncation and keep only the first syllable).  I am trying to think about this as in general English usage, although my immediate application, in this particular case, is to be used in a computing setting.

Maybe I can throw another example here: if I need to abbreviate the word "subscriber", would "sub" (which is often misunderstood as the opposite of "super") or "sbscrbr" a better abbrev?

Comment: This looks like a request for programming advice. I thought programming advice was off topic here. But if it weren't, I would advise you to come up with more easily recognizable names and make sure you are generous with your use of comments. The next guy will appreciate that much more than whether *measure* is abbreviates as *mea* or *msr*.

Comment: I wouldn't use mea, because it immediately brings to mind "mea culpa", which is not a message you want to convey.  I'd use meas.  msr is very close to the abbreviation of Monsignor, a form of address for a distinguished Catholic priest (Msgr).  As far as I know, meas won't be confused with something else.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise consulting the [Online List of the most common abbreviations used in the OED](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/abbreviations/)

```
Meas.    measure
```

Hard to go wrong using an abbreviation from that list.